# mysql select latest by date for all with same name

Tags: mysql

I have a table with points by users:

```
id, created_at, user_id, points
1, 2018-11-01, 1, 20
2, 2018-11-03, 1, 12
3, 2018-11-04, 2, 15
...
```

I now want to select the top 50 users, but only considering the users latest points. i.e. user 1 has two entries and only the latest one (2018-11-03) should count.

expected result:

```
id, created_at, user_id, points
3, 2018-11-04, 2, 15
2, 2018-11-03, 1, 12
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can the maximum values of `created_at` (latest `created_at`) for every `user_id`. You can then join this result-set to the main table, to get only the row corresponding to latest `created_at`.

Now, use this result-set to sort on the `points` in Descending order and consider Top 50 only, using `LIMIT 50`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM your_table AS t
JOIN
( SELECT
    user_id, MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at 
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY user_id 
) AS dt 
  ON dt.user_id = t.user_id AND 
     dt.latest_created_at = t.created_at 
ORDER by t.points DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where created_at in 
(select max(created_at) from tablename b where a.user_id=b.user_id)
order by points desc limit 50
```